# SSRS user denial permission of not editing the web portal page

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have created my SSRS 2012 reporting service and deployed my report which is working well. i added users with brows permission and the user is able to used most of the icons on the webpage, i want to disable all editable feature on the webpage to stop user from editing the web page.

Comment: SSRS permissions are additive. i.e.: if the user account only has Browser or Report Builder permissions, but is also in a Windows Group that has Content Manager or Publisher permissions, the user will have those added on top of their account permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Firstly denied access from  web page editing and just give brows access exactly for report.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but i did and only granted brows right but when he access it from his end, he still have permission to even create folder on the webpage.